# Authenticating Sveltekit with JWT API using cookies

Tags: api, authentication, jwt, svelte, sveltekit

I'm trying to authenticate my Sveltekit front-end with JWT using an HTTPonly cookie for security reasons, but it's not working.

> Error: "Authentication credentials were not provided."

I can't see the cookie in the storage after login.

My Login code:

```
<script>
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

    let username = '';
    let password = '';

    const submit = async () => {
        await fetch('https://myAPI/auth/jwt/create', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                password
            })
        });
     goto('/auth/me');
    };
</script>
```

I must say that the user registration is working fine.

```
<script>
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

    let username = '';
    let password = '';
    let email = '';
    let first_name = '';
    let last_name = '';

    const submitForm = async () => {
        await fetch('https://myAPi/auth/users/', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                password,
                email,
                first_name,
                last_name
            })
        });

        goto('/');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Why do you attempt to include credentials on login POST? Isn't the login endpoint supposed to provide those credentials, i.e. forge the JWT and set the corresponding cookie? Once that cookie is set and returned by the login endpoint, that's when you should include credentials to query other, protected endpoints.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Well, I have tried without the credentials and didn't work neither. The result is always the same, I can not get the JWT cookie. When I try in my API endpoint directly, everything works fine.

Comment: On your Login, the fetch body has an invalid JSON - assuming username and password are String the way you defined it. Also, whats the point of awaiting a goto?

Comment: @miwin can you explain why the JSON is invalid? There is no point in await goto. I saw after paste the code. :)

Comment: Your JSON is missing the key for the value.

Comment: @miwin the JSON is fine. `{ username, password }` is a shorthand for `{ username: username, password: password }`. @J.Reis can you explain what result you are expecting from your first request? Also, showing how you handle that request on the back end would be more interesting than showing the user registration (which adds no relevant value to the question). Thanks!

Comment: @ThomasHennes Well I will try to explain. In the API I created the login with JWT works fine. I make the login and receive one access token and refresh token. With that access token and something like ModHeader extension (to save my token) I can entry in the endpoints where you must be connected to access. With sveltekit I want to connect and somehow save the JWT cookie like HttpOnly to fetch data from the endpoints where authentication is needed. If you need my API route to test yourself, be free to ask. I have also fallowed this tuto "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eDx9igpmRqM&t=958s"

Comment: @J.Reis Thank you. Normally, once you set the cookie on the back-end side, that cookie will be forwarded with your response. On the client side, you would then have to add the `credentials: 'include'` option to *further* fetch requests to protected endpoints to pass along the cookie you previously received (which will, assumedly, hold your JWT, allowing you to authenticate with these protected endpoints).

Comment: @ThomasHennes thanks for the quick response. For some reason I can not get the JWT cookie (i dont see him in the dev tools) and I dont have any error neither, but when I try to fetch some data from one "need auth" endpoint, I have one error "Authentication credentials were not provided." . I have tried in postman to see if the POST request works, and it works. I'm stuck in this thing ...

Comment: @J.Reis I have no reason to doubt that your login request works, I am however curious to know *what* exactly you are doing server-side when you handle that request. Are you explicitly setting a cookie, session or otherwise? Assuming that's when you generate your JWT, what are you doing with it, how are you passing it back to your client? What type of Auth scheme do your protected endpoints expect? Auth 'Bearer' headers? An auth cookie? These are the elements you need to provide in your question.

Comment: @J.Reis I have watched the YT video you linked earlier. If you're using the same API the tutorial author does, then a 'jwt' cookie should be set following the login request. Could you please give me your API endpoints for registering/connecting (assuming they're public-facing)? I'll happily attempt to put together a basic SvelteKit client that connects to it if that can help.

Comment: @ThomasHennes https://joao-back-ecommerce-prod.herokuapp.com/ this is the API I made with Django Rest Framework. You can registe yourself in https://joao-back-ecommerce-prod.herokuapp.com/auth/users/ - Login endpoint: https://joao-back-ecommerce-prod.herokuapp.com/auth/jwt/create - User info: https://joao-back-ecommerce-prod.herokuapp.com/auth/users/me/ .. You have a lot more endpoints that you can search. And for the YT video, the problem is there, I should have my jwt after login, but I don't. Its like the login is working, but the jwt its not stored in my machine, so when I try to fetch...

Comment: ...some data from authenticated endpoints, I have the message "Authentication credentials were not provided." In the dev tools i don't even get the "jwt cookie"

Comment: If you try with Postman with the headers "Content-type : application/json" and "Authorization - JWT "your jwt token" ", everything runs flawless. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe I now have enough elements to provide a more accurate answer.

Your API returns a JWT access token upon successful login, but *does not set any cookie containing that token*. In fact, your API is not reliant on cookies *at all* since the protected route does not expect a cookie containing the JWT token, but instead an Authorization header containing the token.

This is why I was so insistant on you providing a detailed implementation of your back-end.

In the tutorial you followed and linked in your comment, the author explicitly declares his intent to use cookies to authenticate. This choice is reflected on the front-end (through the use of the `credentials: include` option in `fetch`) but *also* on the back-end, as demonstrated, for example, [in the Laravel implementation of his API](https://github.com/scalablescripts/auth-backend/blob/main/app/Http/Controllers/AuthController.php) (line 35), or [in its Node implementation](https://github.com/scalablescripts/node-auth/blob/main/routes/routes.js) (lines 40-43). In both cases, you can see how a 'jwt' cookie is explicitly set and returned by the back-end.

The author also explicitly uses the cookie to read back and verify the token when a request is made to a protected route (see lines 52-54 in the Node example above, for instance).

Your API, however, as I have stated above, does not rely on the same mechanism, but instead expects an 'Authorization' request header to be set.

So you have 2 options here. The simpler option is to adapt your client-side code to function with the Auth mechanism provided by your API. This means storing your token in, for example, sessionStorage, and correctly setting the Authorization header when making requests to protected endpoints:

```js
// login.svelte
<script>
    import { goto } from '$app/navigation';

    let username = '';
    let password = '';

    const submit = async () => {
        const result = await fetch('https://myAPI/auth/jwt/create', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                username,
                password
            })
        });
        const data = await result.json();
        const { refresh, access } = data;
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', access);
        goto('/auth/me');
    };
</script>

// auth/me.svelte
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
    onMount(async () => {
        // read token from sessionStorage
        const token = sessionStorage.getItem('token');
        const result = await fetch('https://myAPI/auth/users/me', {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: { 
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `JWT ${token}`
            }
        });
        const data = await result.json();
        console.log(data);
    });
</script>
```

The alternative option is to modify the Auth mechanism in your API from an 'Authorization' header based mechanism to a cookie based mechanism, if this is really what you want, but this would impact other existing services relying on your API, if any.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Is working. Merci. c'est vraiment gentil de ta part. :)